# Array driving me loop(y)

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Pardon the pun in my title (heh) but this is seriously driving me nuts!
This is my code:

```
for ($i=0;$i < $a;$i++){

    $total = (array)$orders -> Total -> Line[$i];

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($total);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

...It outputs the following:

```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => Subtotal
            [name] => Subtotal
        )

    [0] => 299.99
)

Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => Shipping
            [name] => Shipping
        )

    [0] => 13.36
)

Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => Tax
            [name] => Tax
        )

    [0] => 0.00
)

Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => GiftCertificate
            [name] => Gift certificate discount (117943:@CAC7HXPXFUNNJ3MTGC:63.35 117372:@DK9T9TMTCTCTUWF9GC:250.00)
        )

    [0] => -313.35
)

Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => Total
            [name] => Total
        )

    [0] => 0.00
)
```

My question is: how do I save each dollar amount [0] into a respective variable named according to the array['type']?

Comment: Is this from a `SimpleXML` element?

Comment: Yes Rock...why? Would it be better off as an object?

Comment: Can you show the original XML?  SimpleXML elements can be iterated over using `foreach` without converting it to an array.

Comment: Hi Rocket, thanks for the help. I ended up using a form of David Nguyen's solution -- it gave me the most control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$var[] = array('type' => $total['@attributes']['type'], 'amount' => $total[0])`

Answer (score 3):

Rather than a variable (which could be done with variable variables), I recommend putting them into an array `$prices`, keyed by the `type` attributes.

```
$prices = array();
for ($i=0;$i < $a;$i++){

    $total = (array)$orders -> Total -> Line[$i];

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($total);
    echo '</pre>';

    // Append the price to an array using its type attribute as the 
    // new array key
    $prices[$total['@attributes']['type']] = $total[0];
}
```

Untested, of course, but I believe it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
$total_amount_by_type = array();
for ($i=0;$i < $a;$i++){

    $total = (array)$orders -> Total -> Line[$i];

    $total_amount_by_type[$total->type] = $total[0]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something [like this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
for ($i=0;$i < $a;$i++){
    $total = (array)$orders -> Total -> Line[$i];

    // will create variables $Tax, $GiftCertificate etc
    ${$total['@attributes']['type']} = $total[0];

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($total);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```